How to run pact cdc contract tests parallel?
I write cdc provider tests with pact provider.
@Provider("i-api")
@PactBroker(url = "https://pact.h.com")
@ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
public class ProviderContractEventsTest {

    public ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public JFixture fixture = new JFixture();


    @TestTemplate
    @ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
    void pactVerificationTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context) {
        context.verifyInteraction();
    }
    @BeforeEach
    public void before(PactVerificationContext context) {
        fixture.customise().repeatCount(1);
        context.setTarget(new MessageTestTarget());
    }
    @State("x")
    @PactVerifyProvider("y")
    public String d() throws JsonProcessingException {
        var domain = fixture.create(GMessage.class);
        domain.setItems(Collections.singletonList(fixture.create(GMessage.class)));
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(domain);
    }
    @State("z")
    @PactVerifyProvider("t")
    public String e() throws JsonProcessingException {
        var domain = fixture.create(FMessage.class);
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(domain);
    }
}

I run the tests with below terminal code:
mvn clean test -Dtest="com.c.t.contract.tests.**"
I want to verify all states together as my provider test counts almost 90 and it increases pipeline time. How to do it ?
